# Using Google Analytics in Android service application

Tags: android, analytics

I would like to implement Google Analytics in an Android service based application. The application has a home screen widget and I would like to keep track of certain usage trends. Do I have to use an Application, as indicated in most of the examples? Can't I just use a static variable that will hold the tracker and use it to 'send' info to Google Analytics? Is the Analytics service not working without the reportActivityStart and reportActivityStop calls? I have tried what I have described, I can see the GAV4 logcat output and everything seems to work properly - no errors at all (and DryMode is not set) but I do not see any info on the Google Analytics website.

Here is the code for the class that handles the logging:

```
public class AnalyticsHelper {

    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-xxxxxx-xx";

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
    }

    static HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    synchronized private static Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) { 

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(WidgetHelper.context); 
            analytics.setDryRun(false);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker) : analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
                    mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
        }

        return mTrackers.get(trackerId); 
    }

    public static void sendView(String screenName) {
        Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER); 
        if (t != null) { 
            t.setScreenName(screenName); 
            t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
        }
    }

    public static void sendAction(String category, String action, String label, int value) {
        Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER); 
        if (t != null) { 
            t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
        .setCategory(category)
        .setAction(action) 
        .setLabel(label) 
        .setValue(value) 
        .build());
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the calls to the class for logging an action or a page view, from the home screen service:

```
AnalyticsHelper.sendAction("Service", "Update", "", 0);
...
AnalyticsHelper.sendView("Settings");
```

Comment: can you post code what you have tried to send info to GA?

Comment: I have updated my question with the code. In the meantime, I have noticed that after around 24 hours, I can see some statistics on the Google Analytics website. Does it take that long for data to appear? If it is like this, what about lthe Real time feature? It always shows 0 active users (note that I am the only one using the application so I should see a 1 instead of a 0).

Comment: if you have new account thn yes it takes approx 24 hours to get started and abt real time data it takes 1 min atleast to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

**MyApplication**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UX-XXXXXXXX-Y";
    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;
    private static Context mContext;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, GLOBAL_TRACKER, ECOMMERCE_TRACKER,
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public MyApplication() {
        super();
    }

   public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {

            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics
                    .newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics
                            .newTracker(PROPERTY_ID) : analytics
                            .newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
}
```

**GoogleAnalyticsHelper**

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsHelper {

private Tracker mGaTracker = null;
private static String TAG = "GoogleAnalyticsHelper";


public GoogleAnalyticsHelper()    
{

}
public void init(Context ctx) {
    try {

        if (mGaTracker == null && ctx != null)
        {
            mGaTracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(ctx).newTracker(Constant.PROPERTY_ID);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(GoogleAnalyticsHelper.TAG,"init, e="+e);
    }
}

public void SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics(String screenName, Context iCtx)
{
    init(iCtx);

    mGaTracker.setScreenName(screenName);
    mGaTracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

}


public void SendEventGoogleAnalytics(Context iCtx,String iCategoryId, String iActionId, String iLabelId)
{
    init(iCtx);

        // Build and send an Event.
        mGaTracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
            .setCategory(iCategoryId)
            .setAction(iActionId)
            .setLabel(iLabelId)
            .build());

     }
  }
```

**Send Screen Views in Activity as :**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragmentactivity_kc_test);
        InitGoogleAnalytics();
    }

private void InitGoogleAnalytics()
    {           
        mGoogleHelper = new GoogleAnalyticsHelper();        
        mGoogleHelper.init(FragmentActivity_DashBoard.this);      
    }

    private void SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics()
    {

        mGoogleHelper.SendScreenNameGoogleAnalytics("FragmentActivity_DashBoard",FragmentActivity_DashBoard.this);
    }
```

**Send Event [onClick of any view]**

```
tvOpt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendEventGoogleAnalytics("Button", "on click of test option1",
                        "test option1 clicked");
            }
        });
```

Below is Screenshot for event click in real time tab on GA dashboard

[image]

Comment: Thanks.I have tried the above code with some modifications and it works. I basically moved all the code to the Helper class and got rid of the MyApplication class (since all it did was to just create the helper class). What I do is to create the GaHelper object and then call the sendView or sendEvent functions. The way I had it before was to keep an active helper object in memory all the time and call it from everywhere. I don't know if that was the problem.